# Equivalent definitions of associated prime ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm reading the book *Undergraduate Commutative Algebra* of M. Reid. He gives the following definition: Let $M$ be an $R$-module and let $P$ be an ideal of $R$. Then $P$ is an associated prime if:

> $1.$ $ P\in \text{Spec}(R)$
>   $2.$ there exists $x \in M $ such that $ P = \text{ann}(x) $ or equivalently there exists $N \subset M $ such that $N \cong A/P $.

My question is why the last two statements are equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's label these conditions:

(a) There exists $x \in M$ such that $P = ann(x)$.

(b) There exists a submodule $N$ of $M$ such that $N \cong R/P$.

Assume that condition (a) holds; let's prove (b).  The element $x \in M$ generates a submodule $Rx = \{rx \mid r \in R\}$. There is a homomorphism $R \to Rx \subseteq M$ uniquely determined by sending $1 \mapsto x$. The kernel of this homomorphism is precisely $P = ann(x)$, and the image is precisely $Rx$.  It follows from the first isomorphism theorem for modules that $Rx \cong R/P$. So we can take $N = Rx$ for condition (b).

Now assume that (b) holds, so that $N \cong R/P$ for some submodule $N$ of $M$.  Under this isomorphism, there is some element $x \in N$ that corresponds to the coset $1+P \in R/P$.  You can prove that $ann(1+P) = P$ (REMEMBER: we're considering $R/P$ as an $R$-module, not as a ring unto itself).  Thus, since $x$ corresponds to $1+P$ under the isomorphism, we find that $ann(x) = ann(1+P) = P$. So condition (a) holds.